# how can i show sql header columns in rows in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i want to show these records column wise for particular month and year, like below table format

```
Source   Total
Organic  1252   
Paid     121             
Email  Campaign 121    
Total   1494    

select Organic,Paid ,EmailCampaign ,Total    from tbl_leads where Month='Aug' and  Year='2015'
```

below is sample date

```
Organic Paid    EmailCampaign   Total   ProjectName        Month    Year
4444    5555        2222       1111      demo project       Feb   2015
1252    121          121       1494      debug test         Aug   2015
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sql Server you can use `Cross Apply` with `Tabled Valued Constructor` to unpivot the data

```
SELECT cs.Source,
       cs.Total
FROM   tbl_leads
       CROSS apply (VALUES ('Organic',Organic),
                           ('Paid',Paid),
                           ('EmailCampaign',EmailCampaign),
                           ('Total',Total)) cs(Source, Total)
WHERE  Month = 'Aug'
       AND Year = '2015'
```

Or Generic Sql solution

```
SELECT 'Organic' AS Source,
       Organic   AS Total
FROM   tbl_leads
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Paid',
       Paid
FROM   tbl_leads
UNION ALL
SELECT 'EmailCampaign',
       EmailCampaign
FROM   tbl_leads
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total',
       Total
FROM   tbl_leads
```